# How can I make my View stop unnecessary rendering with using CustomType for Binding in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a **CustomType** called **AppData**, and it look like this:

---

```
struct AppData {
    var stringOfText: String
    var colorOfText: Color
}
```

---

I am using this **AppData** in my Views as State or Binding, I have **2** Views in my project called: **ContentView** and another one called **BindingView**. In my **BindingView** I am just using Color information of **AppData**. And I am expecting that my **BindingView** render or response for Color information changes! How ever in the fact **BindingView** render itself even for `stringOfText` Which is totally unnecessary, because that data is not used in View. I thought that maybe **BindingView** not just considering for `colorOfText` but also for all package that cary this data and that is appData So I decided help **BindingView** to understand when it should render itself, and I made that View ***Equatable***, But that does not helped even. Still **BindingView** refresh and render itself on changes of `stringOfText` which it is wasting of rendering. How can I solve this issue of unnecessary rendering while using **CustomType** as type for my State or Binding.

---

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var appData: AppData = AppData(stringOfText: "Hello, world!", colorOfText: Color.purple)

    var body: some View {

        print("rendering ContentView")

        return VStack(spacing: 20) {

            Spacer()

            EquatableView(content: BindingView(appData: $appData))
            //BindingView(appData: $appData).equatable()

            Spacer()

            Button("update stringOfText from ContentView") { appData.stringOfText += " updated"}

            Button("update colorOfText from ContentView") { appData.colorOfText = Color.red }

            Spacer()

        }

    }
}
```

---

```
 struct BindingView: View, Equatable {

    @Binding var appData: AppData

    var body: some View {

        print("rendering BindingView")

        return Text("123")
            .bold()
            .foregroundColor(appData.colorOfText)

    }

    static func == (lhs: BindingView, rhs: BindingView) -> Bool {
        print("Equatable function used!")
        return lhs.appData.colorOfText == rhs.appData.colorOfText
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

When using `Equatable` (and `.equatable()`, `EquatableView()`) on `Views`, SwiftUI makes some decisions about when to apply our own `==` functions and when it is going to compare the parameters on its own. See another one of my answers with more details about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66617961/560942

In this case, it appears that even if `Equatable` is declared, SwiftUI skips it because it must be deciding that the `POD` (plain old data) in the `Binding` is determined to be non-equal and therefore it's going to refresh the view (again, even though one would think that the `==` would be enough to force it not to).

In the example you gave, obviously it's trivial for the system to re-render the `Text` element, so it doesn't really matter if this re-render happened. But, in the even that there actually are consequences to re-rendering, you could encapsulate the non-changing parts into a separate child view:

```
struct BindingView: View {
    @Binding var appData: AppData

    var body: some View {
        print("rendering BindingView")
        return BindingChildView(color: appData.colorOfText)
    }

    //no point in declaring == since it won't get called (at least with the current parameters
}

struct BindingChildView : View {
    var color: Color
    
    var body: some View {
        print("rendering BindingChildView")
        return Text("123")
            .bold()
            .foregroundColor(color)
    }
}
```

In the above code, although the `BindingView` is re-rendered each time (although at basically zero cost, because nothing will change), the new child view is skipped because its parameters are equatable (even without declaring Equatable). So, in a non-contrived example, if the child view were expensive to render, this would solve the issue.

Comment: thanks for answering, I appreciate your solving way, but in the fact you are not using CustomType as Binding! If I would solve my problem in your logical way, why I should even send the all package to BindingView at first place? I could easy make your implantation right away in BindingView, which accepting just Color Binding, like: Binding<Color>. My all idea of asking this question was using CustomType without casting that CustomType to another one. It seems SwiftUI with all charming looks has issue in simple logic like this issue we are facing!

Comment: "why I should even send the all package to BindingView at first place?" Good question. In your original question, there's no reason to. The answerer has to make assumptions about what *might* be happening, like I did with the idea that perhaps there's a subview with an expensive render. That's the problem with these hypothetical questions without a real-world example. However, I don't know what you're saying with "casting CustomType to another one" -- I didn't do any casting. I also don't really think this is a case of SwiftUI having an issue with "simple logic".

Comment: "casting CustomType to another one" I wanted say that you are converting CustomType to a type that make no problem for use, my idea was not converting.

Comment: I guess I'm pretty confused about what would constitute an answer for you on this question.

Comment: I am sorry, let me explain in another way, if you see my code style, I am using **AppData** type in my project, this Type has all data that app needs to work, I want use **@State/Binding var appData: AppData** in my Views, to get access the all possible data, that can be accessed, and every View can take what it needs, like my example code, **BindingView** just need the Color information.

Comment: But if `BindingView` just needs the color info, why not just pass the color info to it (as I did in my example). Why is there the requirement to send the entire `appData`?

Comment: that is first possible way to do that and that is like erasing problem and call it solved, I can do that way like every one does, but the idea is having a type like river of data folding in every View, and every View take what they need. that is the idea.

Comment: "type like river of data folding in every View" but *why*? Why create an artificial requirement on top of it (that for some reason you have to have *all* the data) even though it breaks what you want to happen (not re-rendering)? Is there any reason in a real-world example?

Comment: So you and I we know what about we are talking right? What if, that SwiftUI could take my CustomType as Binding and just render if the body needed, that would mega cool right? So as we know SwiftUI is not clever for that right now! and that is why I want find a way to solve the issue.

Comment: I guess my assumption on this site would be that since none of us are engineers on the SwiftUI team that we're trying to find answers to work with the existing framework to solve real-world problems, since we can't change the underlying way that the framework works today.

Comment: thanks for help and time, I am voting and letting this question open to answer, maybe someone knows more than what we know right now.