# Xcode Bus error: 10 when archiving but working fine on debug

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, optimization, swiftui

#### Xcode 13.4.1 (13F100)

A project using **SwiftUI** fails **archiving** and throws the very cryptic message `Bus error: 10`, without further explanation.

But everything works fine while debugging.

After some fiddling with the project **Build Settings**, specifically the differences between **Debug** and **Release** modes I narrowed the problem to be around `Optimization Level`. Using `Optimize for Speed [-0]` (my Release configuration) will throw the error, but if I change it to `No Optimization [-0none]` the error is gone and I can archive.

How can I fix the problem without compromising optimization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long research and reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66617961/4691224) answer I was able to narrow the issue even further. It turned out I had a `SwiftUI` `EquatableView`, but without properties. Something like this:

#### Not working for Optimization

```swift
struct MyEquatableView: View, Equatable {
    var body: some View {
        // some content
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        // some logic
    }
}
```

All I had to do was adding a "dummy property" to my `View`:

#### Compatible with Optimization

```swift
struct MyEquatableView: View, Equatable {
    private let id = UUID() // dummy property
    
    var body: some View {
        // some content
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        // some logic
    }
}
```